# Como converter um objeto para boolean em Ruby?

Tags: ruby, conversão-de-tipo, booleano

Os objetos em Ruby tem alguns métodos para representação em outro tipo, como:

- `to_s`: converter para string
- `to_a`: converter para array
- `to_i`: converter para inteiro
- `to_f`: converter para float

Mas não existe um método padrão para converter um objeto para booleano, nem na classe `Object`. Como fazer essa conversão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maneira idiomática de converter um objeto de qualquer tipo para boolean em Ruby é usando uma dupla negação (também chamado de *double bang* na comunidade Ruby):

```
def to_b(obj)
  !!obj
end
```

A dupla negação não afeta o valor, tal que:

```
!!true  => true
!!false => false
```

Vale lembrar que em Ruby, tudo é verdadeiro, exceto `nil` e `false`. Portanto:

```
to_b "olá" => true
to_b 0     => true
to_b ""    => true
to_b true  => true
to_b nil   => false
to_b false => false
```

Comment: Não seria mais adequado usar `to_b "olá"` ao invés de `"olá".to_b`?

Comment: @LuizFelipe editado, obrigado ;)